# Quickload inside eval-when

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp

Here's a strange situation. I have this code:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload "cffi-grovel")
  (setf cffi-grovel::*cc* "mpicc")) ; <--- this is the line it complains about.
```

Which I belive has to load `cffi-grovel` package before setting `cffi-grovel::*cc*` variable. When this form is executed from SLIME it works, but it doesn't work when loaded directly by SBCL, here's the output:

```
$ sbcl --noinfo
* (ql:quickload "cl-mpi")

debugger invoked on a LOAD-SYSTEM-DEFINITION-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10029C0E43}>:
  Error while trying to load definition for system cl-mpi from pathname
  /home/wvxvw/quicklisp/local-projects/cl-mpi/cl-mpi.asd:
     READ error during COMPILE-FILE:

       Package CFFI-GROVEL does not exist.

         Line: 6, Column: 25, File-Position: 264

< restarts ... >

* (ql:quickload "cffi-grovel")
To load "cffi-grovel":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cffi-grovel
; Loading "cffi-grovel"
..
("cffi-grovel")
* (ql:quickload "cl-mpi")
To load "cffi-grovel":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cffi-grovel
; Loading "cffi-grovel"

To load "cl-mpi":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-mpi
; Loading "cl-mpi"
; mpicc -m64 ...
; ...
.
("cl-mpi")
```

Why does it fail the first time?

PS. I also tried `#.cffi-grovel::*cc*` instead - same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

monoid gives a good answer. Here is a slightly shorter form.

Find the symbol at runtime, when the package actually exists. Note the use of `SET`, not `SETF` here:

```
(set (find-symbol "*CC*" "CFFI-GROVEL") "mpicc")
```

To make it more robust, one would need to check that `FIND-SYMBOL` actually finds the symbol.
The following function also gives you meaningful error messages and restarts:

```
(defun set-runtime-symbol (name package value)
  (assert (find-package package) (package))
  (assert (find-symbol name package) (name))
  (set (find-symbol name package) value))
```

Alternatively use two EVAL-WHEN statements, instead of one.

Comment: Additional information from CLHS: "The function SET is deprecated."

Comment: @Lars Brinkhoff: I would not really care what the CLHS says about 'deprecation'. `SET` is not going away soon.

Answer (score 6):

It fails because Lisp reads every form before executing it.  And when it reads it, package cffi-grovel indeed does not exist yet, because cffi-grovel is loaded at execution time (whatever it means for form wrapped with eval-when).

Try spliting the eval-when form into two eval-whens: ql:quickload and setf.  Or write something like this:

```
(setf (symbol-value (find-symbol "*CC*" "CFFI-GROVEL"))
      "mpicc")
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally figured it I can do it like so:

```
(setf #.(intern "cffi-grovel::*cc*") "mpicc")
```

But I'm not sure how much this is fail-safe.

Comment: Usually you would need to upcase the symbol and package names. Also INTERN takes two arguments: a name and a package. Good: INTERN would complain if the package does not exist.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Yes, that's a copy-paste error, the actual code used upper case name.